# ReactJS - node-telegram-bot-api (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'))

Tags: reactjs, node-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to import the node-telegram-bot-api in my react app like so:`
`import TelegramBot from "node-telegram-bot-api";`

But upon doing this I get the following error in my console. 
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmO5D.png)

This error is created upon importing alone and nothing else. 
Is anyone able to help solve this issue?

Comment: How can we help you without checking your code?

Comment: Share the code where you're getting errors.

Comment: I am simply getting the error by importing, nothing other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is for nodejs as its name [see](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) that's why it's causing the issue. You can refer to this for Reactjs [here](https://github.com/evgeny-nadymov/telegram-react) maybe it will helpful for you.